# MATLAB - Can someone please just explain what these lines of code do

Tags: matlab

Hi can someone help me regarding this code, i know that it reads the image and shows the red channel on the histogram for the RGB image (Fruits1).

```
colourImage = imread('Fruits1.jpg');        //read image  
redHistogram = double(colourImage(:,:,1));  //what does this line do?  
figure, hist(redHistogram(:),124);          //what does this line do?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
redHistogram = double(colourImage(:,:,1));  //what does this line do?
```

This takes the red plane of the image and converts each pixel intensity from an integer (0-255) to a floating-point value (double).  The result is a 2-d array of these values.

```
figure, hist(redHistogram(:),124);          //what does this line do?
```

This displays a histogram of the pixel intensities from above, sorted into 124 equal-sized bins.